# Vue Webpack: After upload to shared hosting url refresh return 404 Not Found

Tags: firebase, webpack, vue.js, firebase-hosting

Well this is my first project with Vue and Firebase. I run the project locally and everything work perfect. After upload the dist file to my share hosting everything works fine except the URL. When I make any refresh it brings me 404 Not Found page.

**Note:**  Everything works fine on my localserver.

Comment: Can you share your firebase.json file and if you use a router, your router.js file

Comment: please check ....I add my firebase, router and main.js file

Answer (score 0):

You provide little information (close to none at all), so I have to guess:

you didn't configure your backend to support a router running in history mode.

how to do that depoends on the backend you are using - some solutions are documented in the router docs here:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

If your shared hosting doesn't allow you to customize the config accordingly, you will have to either:

- switch to 'hash' mode for routing
- find a better hosting provider